# How would I create a "infinite" loops until the user decides to call it quits?

Tags: java, loops

I'm having a slight problem.
I have a menu asking to:

- reroll
- get val
- show max
- show min

when the user chooses an option I want it to do one of them THEN re ask the menu in a sort of inifinite loop:

code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

class RecordDice {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int dSides, Sides, Choice;
        int max, min;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many sides should the dice have?");
        Sides = s.nextInt();
        if(Sides == 4 || Sides == 6 || Sides == 12  || Sides == 20 ||  Sides == 100){
            System.out.println("Please make a choice:\n" +
                "1 - reroll the dice\n" +
                "2 - get the value\n" +
                "3 - show the maximum\n" +
                "4 - show the minimum");
        } else {
            System.exit(-1); 
        }

        Dice2 d = new Dice2(Sides);
        int Choice = c.nextInt();

        int Value = d.getValue();

        switch(Choice){
            case 1:
                System.out.println();
                d.reroll();
                break;
            case 2: 
                System.out.println("The current value is " + Value);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("The maximum is " );
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("The minimun is ");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Would putting the menu in a method and just calling the method every time a option is picked?

Comment: First, *add* a loop around the code that should be looped. Once that is done, it should be relatively easy to figure out the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `"5 - quit"` to your menu.

Create a `boolean`, something like `exit`, initialized to `false`.

Add `case 5: exit = true; break;`

Then wrap the whole thing in `while(!exit)`

---

```
boolean exit = false;

while(!exit) {
    //all the code you already have, starting with:
    System.out.println("How many sides should the dice have?");
    //and ending with the switch statement
    //Plus the addition to the menu and addition to the switch statement
}
```

---

Ordinarily, I would do something like:

```
while(true) {
    //do stuff
    if(someExitCondition) {
        break;
    }
}
```

But seeing how as you're handling your user input with a `switch` statement, my above suggested method seems to be the cleanest way of handling it in this scenario.

Comment: Even without a quit option, the user can just Ctrl-C to exit.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail You should avoid coding programs that can only be terminated by holding a gun to the program's head and pulling the trigger - the real-life equivalent of Ctrl-C ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop to keep displaying it.

```
boolean keepGoing = true;
While(keepGoing)
 {
  //your code
 }
```

Then to end  it ask the user if they want to end it an set the boolean to false.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it all in a do-while loop.

```
boolean userWantsToQuit = false;
do {
// code
// evaluate userWantsToQuit…
} while (!userWantsToQuit);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean keepGoing=true;
while(keepGoing)
{
//user input
if(user input to exit)
{
keepGoing=false;
}
}
```

or

```
while(true)
{
//user input
if(user input to exit)
{
break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming selection of dice sides you will allow only once, put code below that in do while loop.
2. You may prompt user "Do you wish to continue" after your switch block.
3. Get that value scanned
4. Condition in while loop will be something list while("YES".equals(userInput)).. assuming user will input YES or NO strings.